# What changes are expected in chemical reaction when deuterium(D) is attached in place of hydrogen(H)

Tags: organic-chemistry

Our teachers told that deuterium (D) in place of H in organic reaction only matters when the C-H is broken in a reaction . But does it really matter only then ? Will it affect the stability of the compound so formed ?

Comment: There are whole reviews written about the deuterium effect. Here is one of them: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr50004a004

Comment: Approximately 0.01% of already existing C-H bonds are actually C-D bonds. The teacher probably meant dynamic  replacement of active hydrogen, e.g. C2H5OH + D2O <=> C2O5OD + HDO, or CH3COCH2COCH3 + D2O <=> CH3COCHDCOCH3 + HDO